# PGP Secret Key Values calculation

Tags: cryptography, pgp

I know this is somewhat counterintuitive, but: Does anyone know of any place where I might get intermediate values from PGP when it decrypts the secret values of the Secret Key packets and shows explicitly any special parsing needed to be done on the bytes?

Im looking for something like:

> Given some example private key block and its password:
>
> 1. the encrypted secret value is _____
> 2. the password is transformed into ____ using the string to key algorithm
> 3. the internal values in the CFB decryption using key and encrypted data are ____ , ____, and ____

> etc.

I have read through [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), but since there are no examples of actual encryptions/decryptions in the RFC, I cannot be sure if my code is correct. I have looked through some of gpg, but its code is filled with so many `gmd_`s and other variables that all look the same and I get extremely confused, adding to the problem of me not always knowing where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the test vectors in the GnuPG \tests\openpgp folder? The GnuPG source can be downloaded from [here](http://www.gnupg.org/download/index.en.html#gnupg2).